# Need help in implementing tablesorter 2.17.1(or latest)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, tablesorter

can anybody please help me get a working sample of MVC application with  [tablesorter plugin](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html) applied ? I am a bit confused about how to apply latest tablesorter plugin to my MVC sample..I am trying to implement something like

```
$('table').trigger('sortReset')
```

in the below teble.

```
<table class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>AlphaNumeric Sort</th>
            <th>Currency</th>
            <th>Alphabetical</th>
            <th>Sites</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>abc 123</td><td>&#163;10,40</td><td>Koala</td><td>http://www.google.com</td></tr>
        <tr><td>abc 1</td><td>&#163;234,10</td><td>Ox</td><td>http://www.yahoo.com</td></tr>
        <tr><td>abc 9</td><td>&#163;10,33</td><td>Girafee</td><td>http://www.facebook.com</td></tr>
        <tr><td>zyx 24</td><td>&#163;10</td><td>Bison</td><td>http://www.whitehouse.gov/</td></tr>
        <tr><td>abc 11</td><td>&#163;3,20</td><td>Chimp</td><td>http://www.ucla.edu/</td></tr>
        <tr><td>abc 2</td><td>&#163;56,10</td><td>Elephant</td><td>http://www.wikipedia.org/</td></tr>
        <tr><td>abc 9</td><td>&#163;3,20</td><td>Lion</td><td>http://www.nytimes.com/</td></tr>
        <tr><td>ABC 10</td><td>&#163;87,00</td><td>Zebra</td><td>http://www.google.com</td></tr>
        <tr><td>zyx 1</td><td>&#163;99,90</td><td>Koala</td><td>http://www.mit.edu/</td></tr>
        <tr><td>zyx 12</td><td>&#163;234,10</td><td>Llama</td><td>http://www.nasa.gov/</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Also the js and css files I am referring are as follows

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Basic Tablesorter Demo</title>


<link href="~/Content/jq.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="~/Content/theme.default.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.tablesorter').tablesorter({
            widgets: ['zebra', 'columns'],
            usNumberFormat: false,
            sortReset: true,
            sortRestart: true
        });
    });

</script>
```

Not sure why I am not getting this working..It thorows an error like "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function " for tablesorter()

Note: I learned that this functionality of resetting is available with plugin 2.4.7 onward.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add an element on the page that allows the user to click to reset the sort. In [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/3127/), I'll use a button:

```
<button type="button" class="reset">Reset Sort</button>
```

then apply the appropriate script to give that button the ability to trigger the reset event:

```
$(function () {
    $('.tablesorter').tablesorter({
        widgets: ['zebra', 'columns'],
        usNumberFormat: false,
        sortReset: true,
        sortRestart: true
    });

    // make button reset the sort
    $('.reset').click(function(){
        $('.tablesorter').trigger('sortReset');
    });

});
```

Alternatively, the user can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Left Click on any header cell to reset the sort. The key can be changed using the [`sortResetKey` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#sortresetkey).

Comment: Thanks @Mottie. your example works well in jsfiddle..But the problem I am still facing is, it doesn't apply the tablesorter theme to the html table.I get this working for tablesorter 2.0.0 though.

Comment: Ohhhhh..I got where the problem lies at. I was referring to the Jquery.1.8.1.min.js twice .One in _Layout .cshtml and on the page itself.I now removed one of them and got this worked pretty well....Thanks @Mottie...

Comment: Also @Mottie, cannot we user sortList{} for multi column sorting ? DO we need to use sortOn{} for this version of tablesorter ? Can you please update that in your example in jsfiddle ?

Comment: I used like ` sortList=[[0, 0], [1, 1]]        
        $("table").trigger("sorton", [sortList]);` and it worked